Any workaround for disabling prisma interactive transaction?
My case is something like a db call, a post request, and a db call. All wrapped inside a transaction. So I'd like the transaction to fail when the post request fails or any other db call fails. So if the time for post request exceeds the timeout, the transaction is cancelled.
const user = await tx.user.create(/.../);

const result = await api(user.id);

await tx.other.update(...);

So is there any workaround for disabling the interactive transaction timeout except setting it absurdly large value?
